# How to import LWC shared code from extra js file from withing the component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to import the following (highlighted in yellow) file into my LWC component-[image]

I am trying to import mycomponent-share.js into the mycomponent.js.
The mycomponent-share.js contains the following code-

```
export function isFunction(value) {
return typeof value === 'function';
}
```

I am using the following code to import it into mycomponent.js

```
import { isFunction } from 'mycomponent-share'
```

But this is not working, please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell the LWC compiler to use a relative path:

```
import { isFunction } from './mycomponent-share';
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem.

Comment: @user2246808 Please accept the answer, so it will help other people.

Comment: Is there some way to specify that the extension ".js" should be accepted in the import name?