# Importing Function from LWC js File returns 'Is Not Function'

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, function

Trying to figure out how to share JS functions with another component. I have followed the documentation on the [LWC here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_javascript_share_code)

Here is the functions.js file
**reusableLWCFunctions.js**

```
const myfunction = (myString) => {

    console.log(myString);
    return myString;
};

export{
    myfunction
};
```

Here is the LWC that calls the function.

Currently I get the following error: **reuseableLWCFunctions.myFunction is not a function**

```
import { myFunction } from 'c/reuseableLWCFunctions';

export default class myLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    constructor(){
        super();
        myFunction('THIS WAS CALLED FROM IMPORTED FUNCTION');
    }
```

Not sure why it's breaking the component and not firing the console.log statement.

Any help would be great:

Already tried the solution on [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290341/how-to-import-lwc-shared-code-from-extra-js-file-from-withing-the-component)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to make this call from the `connectedCallback()` method. doing so will have resolved your import by this time. See below:

```
import { myfunction } from 'c/reusableLWCFunctions';

export default class myLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){

    connectedCallback(){
      myfunction('THIS WAS CALLED FROM IMPORTED FUNCTION');
    }

}
```

the constructor for your case would really be useless. in fact in most cases I don't even see the need in using it. `connectedCallback` is where you want to make any calls to your imports.

Comment: Trying now, will let you know result.

Comment: I'm still not seeing anything in the Console log from the function. Doesn't appear to be firing...

Comment: do you have the HTML template for this?

Comment: wait - let me fix my casing. i believe you may not be even importing it due to miscased method name. updating my response.

Comment: Yes, but the HTML renders fine. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with that.

Comment: see if you fix your casing to match with your sample method that it takes care of this for you.

Comment: That did it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you're welcome.